# Some issue with docker image in yml file. unable to runmy pipeline after adding a new runner in gitlab

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I have configured my project to run on a pipeline
Here is my .git.yml file content:

```yaml
image: markhobson/maven-chrome:latest

stages:
  - flow1

execute job1:
  stage: flow1
  tags:
    - QaFunctional
  script:
    - export
    - set +e -x
    - mvn --update-snapshots --define updateResults=${updateResults}  clean test
```

Error after executing the pipeline :

```
bash: line 328: mvn: command not found
Running after_script
00:00
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 127
```

Can anyone help me spot the error please ?
Is that not able to load the  docker image?
When I use a shared runner I am able to execute the same.

Answer (score 1):

Error you get means there is no maven installed on job executor `mvn: command not found`

Looks like image you specified `image: markhobson/maven-chrome:latest` has maven command:

```sh
# docker run markhobson/maven-chrome:latest mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
```

Other thing you specified is [`tags`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags):

```yaml
...
  tags:
    - QaFunctional
...
```

So when both `image` and `tags` are specified in your yaml then `tags` takes precedence and `image` is ignored.

Looks like your custom runner tagged with `QaFunctional` is shell runner without mvn configured.

As a solution either install mvn on `QaFunctional` or run job on docker runner (shared runners should do). To avoid such confusion don't specify `image` when you want to run your job on tagged shell runner.